# Sparse block matrices all wrong

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, sparse-arrays

I need to represent $M-\lambda\cdot\textrm{Identity}$ where $M$ is an operator on $V_1\oplus\cdots\oplus V_n$ made from
$$
V_1\xrightarrow{M_1}V_2\xrightarrow{M_2}\cdots\xrightarrow{M_{n-1}}V_n\xrightarrow{M_n}V_1.
$$
With, say, $n=3$, $\dim V_k=k+1$, I am trying

```
sa =
 With[{dim = {2, 3, 4}},   
  With[{n = Length[dim]},    
   SparseArray[
    {
     Band[{1, 1}] -> Table[λ IdentityMatrix[dim[[k]]], {k, n}],
     Band[{2, 1}] -> 
      Table[
       Table[Indexed[M[k], {i, j}], {i, dim[[k + 1]]}, {j, dim[[k]]}], 
       {k, n - 1}
      ],
     Band[{1, n}] -> Table[Indexed[M[n], {i, j}], {i, dim[[1]]}, {j, dim[[n]]}]
    }
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

The result is very strange: both `sa//TableForm` and `ArrayFlatten[sa]//TableForm` give

[image]

The same happens with `Band[{1, n}] -> {Table[...]}`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't the last matrix be placed on `Band[{1, Quotient[n (n + 1), 2]}]`?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Tried. Wrong again (in a different way) - among other things, it is not square anymore. Besides, I don't see why should it be placed there...

Comment: Then try `Band[{1, n (n - 1)/2 + 1}]`. The second index of the band of the last matrix should the sum of the dimensions of the others `+1`

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Now it gives correct answer. However with, say, `dim = {2, 3, 4}` it is all wrong again. As for your explanation: it should be an $n\times n$ array of matrices, should not it?

Comment: Maybe actually I will replace the example with this one, it is more illustrative...

Comment: Then you should use `Total[Most[dim]] + 1`.

Comment: Tried this too. Now (with the new example that I replaced the old one with) the first two rows are ok; however the first rows of other blocks still become chopped off by some reason, and these blocks are shifted up. And I still believe that dimensions of `sa` must be `{n, n}`, it is `ArrayFlatten[sa]` that must have dimensions `{Total[dim], Total[dim]}`, not `sa` itself, no?

Comment: Ah, this last command actually gave me a hint on what you were thinking how it should work.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Yes, what confused me is the very existence of `ArrayFlatten` - I thought it was precisely for such cases. While in fact it seems to become arrayflattened from the beginning...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78462/discussion-between-henrik-schumacher-and--).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SparseArray` reacts different when lists of matrices appear on the right hand side of `Rule` for `Band`. In this case, it assembles the `ArrayFlatten`ed block matrix instead of the matrix of blocks and `Band[{i,j}]` refers to the positions in the final, assembled matrix, not to the position within the matrix of blocks. I have to admit that this is really counterintuitive.

```
sa[dim_] := With[{n = Length[dim]},
  SparseArray[{
    Band[{1, 1}] -> λ,
    Band[{dim[[1]] + 1, 1}] -> 
     Table[Table[ Indexed[M[k], {i, j}], {i, dim[[k + 1]]}, {j, dim[[k]]}], {k, n - 1}], 
    Band[{1, Total[Most[dim]] + 1}] -> 
     Table[Indexed[M[n], {i, j}], {i, dim[[1]]}, {j, dim[[n]]}]},
   {Total[dim], Total[dim]}
   ]
  ]
sa[{2, 3, 4}]
```

There is also the undocumented function `` SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix `` in which you can use `{i,j}-> ...` for the block in the `i`-row and `j`-th column. But `` SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix `` does not go well with `Band`. And it is undocumented, so one has to go mostly by trial and error.

Comment: Wow. I still don't understand why it should work this way but it works!

Comment: Accepted. That seems to be the way it is, so...

Comment: I wonder what will happen with a sparse array of sparse arrays! Fortunately I don't need this :)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way without using `Band`:

```
sA = Module[{dim = #, n = Length @ #, l = Array[\[FormalX], Length @ #], 
     lim = λ IdentityMatrix[Total @ #], mats},
 mats = Table[Indexed[M[k], {i, j}], {k, n}, {i, dim[[Mod[k + 1, n, 1]]]}, {j, dim[[k]]}];
 SparseArray[ArrayFlatten[RotateRight[DiagonalMatrix[l]] /. Thread[l -> mats]] + lim]] &;
```

Examples:

```
MatrixForm @ sA @ {2, 3, 4}
```

[image]

```
MatrixForm @ sA @ {2, 3, 4, 3}
```

[image]